# Indexes on foreign key in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have simple code.

```
CREATE TABLE foo (

client_id int,
order_id int,

PRIMARY KEY (client_id, order_id),
INDEX (order_id),

FOREIGN KEY (client_id) REFERENCES baz(id),
FOREIGN KEY (order_id) REFERENCES bar(id)

);
```

I know that MySQL will automatic add index to column with primary key, but what if I have complex primary key? (example in my code). Why I must add index to second column in primary key? I think that MySQL will automatic add index only for first column but to second, third ... I must add this constraint manually? Is any answer in official documentation?

Answer (score 0):

you can refer to the link
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html

if any table has a multi-column index for eg: `(col1, col2, col3)`, then you can have the search capabilities for `(col1)`, `(col1, col2)`, and `(col1, col2, col3)`

This index will never be used if the search do not form a Left most prefix on the index, which in this case is `col1`

So you need to have `col1` as prefix and a search with `col2,col3` wont use the index

You might need a different index for the same, so you will have to index `col2` separately